# WebSockets. Fleck or websocket-sharp

Tags: websocket

I try to create simple chat application using WebSockets and Fleck or WebSocket-sharp library. I saw few examples but don't understand how to create this type of projects, how to enable web-services in visual studio and so on. I don't have experience with ASP.NET or HTML5. Can you explain me what I need to create simple project (consequence of actions) or give me few links where it is explained step-by-step?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which one did you end up choosing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also created a WebSocket framework named [WebSocketListener](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/)

I have an example of how to create a [chat application](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Chat-application-using-Reactive-Extennsions-%28RX%29).

Comment: Can you share with me your project? I don't understand how to build it

Comment: You can find the source code here: https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/tree/master/samples/RxWebSocketChat

Comment: One project is the WebSocket server, and the other contains the web application that consumes it.